# is <View alignItems="center"> valid prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I just accidentally discovered that props like `<View alignItems="center">` are actually working in react-native giving view defined css style, is this valid, as I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Comment: wow. it works! I guess it's supposed to be a secret because I also can't find any documentation on it

Comment: Generally if it's not documented it's because it's not officially supported yet and could easily break or disappear in the future. On the other hand sometimes they're simply behind on updating the docs to be current. Use at your own risk.